Are a high BufferCacheHitRatio and a high TotalIOPS mutually exclusive?
I'm currently going through the AWS RDS documentation and trying to get a better understanding of how these metrics are related with each other.
The metric TotalIOPS is said to be the sum of the read and write IOPS, while
the AWS docs state the following for both ReadIOPS and WriteIOPS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-metrics.html
[...]
ReadIOPS: The average number of disk read I/O operations per second.
WriteIOPS: The average number of disk write I/O operations per second.
[...]

The article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/planning-i-o-in-amazon-aurora/ states:

This [buffer cache hit ratio] metric reflects how often a page is found in the
buffer pool rather than reading it from disk.

So, are a high TotalIOPS and high BufferCacheHitRatio mutually exclusive?
Building up on this, does this even mean that if I've a BufferCacheHitRatio of
100%, the TotalIOPS would actually be 0?
